# AJAX request returning JS and not HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails app that includes pagination and an ajax call on `will_paginate` for infinite scroll.

The app makes an ajax call and when the ajax call is initiated it gets JS formatted data as opposed to HTML.

The issue I am having is that my app is showing that it is getting the next page of links based on the logs. Also, when I visit my site on Localhost, the next page in the paginated links are highlighted, but the content of those links is not rendered.

When I first load my page before any AJAX call, this is the request my logs return (HMTL):

```
Started GET "/links?_=1451425008835&page=1" for ::1 at 2015-12-29 16:46:27 -0500
Processing by LinksController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1451425008835", "page"=>"1"}
  Link Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  ORDER BY "links"."cached_votes_score" DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links"
```

Now when the AJAX call gets made to return the next page of my paginated links, this is the request my app is making (JS):

```
Started GET "/links?_=1451425588932&page=2" for ::1 at 2015-12-29 16:47:33 -0500
Processing by LinksController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1451425588932", "page"=>"2"}
  Link Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  ORDER BY "links"."cached_votes_score" DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links"
```

Below are my scripts, controllers, and views.

links_controller.rb:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_score: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

_link.html.erb (rendered in index view):

```
<!-- order links based on total number of votes -->
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>
      <%= image_tag link.avatar_url(:thumb).to_s %>
    </h2>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <%= link_to link.url, link %><br>
    </p>

<!-- acts_as_votable for like_link -->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
          Downvote
          <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% unless @links.empty? %>
  <%= will_paginate @links %>
<% end %>
```

index.js.erb:

```
$('#link').append('<%= j render(@links) %>');
<% if @links.next_page %>
 $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@links) %>');
<% else %>
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

link.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
    $(window).scroll ->
        url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
        if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
            $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
            $.getScript(url)
```

Comment: How are you distinguishing between HTML and JS? Can you post the output of whatever JS and HTML you are referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the Sitepoint example, so I refer you to halfway down where it indicates:

> The PostController#index method should respond to both HTML and JavaScript. We are going to use respond_to to achieve that:

In case you aren't using this site as the reference, here it is: [Infinite scrolling basics](http://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/)

What they do is add:

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

So for you that would be:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_score: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the api dock for that: [`respond_to` ActionController](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)

Edit: you also need a `<div id = "link">`

> In your web developer console does $('#link') return an object? In your HTML I find no  but I do see one with a class. In a CSS selector # is ID and . is class. Give your div an id='link' attribute if there isn't one

Comment: Last night I updated my controller with the respond to js and html. It still doesn't work.

Comment: In your web developer console does `$('#link')` return an object?  In your HTML I find no <div id="link"> but I do see one with a class.  In a CSS selector # is ID and . is class.  Give your div an id='link' attribute if there isn't one.

Comment: What a simple fix. Thank you x1000 for being a second pair of eyes and taking a look at this. If you want to post that comment as an answer, I will accept it.